# iOS - view from table view won't display nav bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a navigation controller leading to a table view, which leads to a detail view. There is an add button leading to another table view to choose from a contacts list. When I select DONE, I want to lead to a new detail view, but the navigation bar won't display. Below is an image of the IB:

[image: image of IB]

So I want to move from the Contacts View Controller to the Convo View Controller but keep the navigation item working.

The code that is executed when the DONE button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
   BOOL sharing = NO;
   if ([self.referrer isEqualToString:@"mapView"]) sharing = YES;
   Convo *newConvo = [[Convo alloc] initWithMembers:self.selectedContacts 
                                                             sharing:sharing];
   // add newConvo to convos list

   ConvoViewController *convoVC = [self.storyboard   
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"convoView"];
   convoVC.convo = newConvo;
   NSLog(@"%@", [convoVC.convo memberListToString]);
   [self presentViewController:convoVC
                      animated:YES
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What navigation bar won't display? The one you think you should have in convoVC?

Comment: Yes. Currently it's just the 'Names' title there, but that doesn't display at runtime.

Comment: That's because convoVC is a new instance, not related to the one you have on your storyboard, and since you didn't embed it in a navigation controller, it's not going to have one.

Comment: So how could I change it to allow me to move from contacts VC to convo VC, with a back button on convo VC that would go to master VC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do what you're trying to do, by embedding the ContactsViewController in its own navigation controller, and segueing (from the Done button) to the new instance of ConvoViewController (the one with the title of "Contacts Detail"). In that controller I have a bar button item called "Main Table" that's connected to an unwind segue that unwinds back to MasterViewController. Here is the setup,

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I apologies I may not have been clear on what I wanted it to do specifically. I want to go from the contacts view controller to the convo view controller, then on the convo view controller be able to move back to the master view controller.

Comment: @mcw, that's what the storyboard I show in my answer does. Both the orange controllers are ConvoViewControllers, but they're different instances (which they would be in the way you're doing it also). I assume that you want to show different info in the detail controller depending on whether you get there from MasterViewController or ContactsViewController.